# What cause all my windows software menu drop from the right side

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I have Windows 7 I have just install it into my PC. I realized That all menus in all software and the quick launch menu start appear in the very left position, and some software like Adobe lightroom all menu behave the same it all appear in the very left side of the drop menu while it is expected to be started from the very right side.

How to adjust my menus to appear just in the right side from my click?

the following is what it appears on my PC

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some quick Googling and the solutions seems to be in tablet PC input settings, [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/786-menus-open-left-right-side.html) is a link you can check out for a step-by-step with pictures.

To resolve the issue you will need to edit the registry.

1. Press Windows Key + R to open the run prompt.
2. Type regedit
3. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
4. If you see something called MenuDropAlignment double click it, if not follow the steps below
    4a. Right click in the white area in the right hand pane
    4b. Click New, then String Value
    4c. Name it MenuDropAlignment
    4d. Double click it now to open it
5. In the value data field type "1" without quotes for it to open to the left, for the right type "0"
6. Close regedit and log off and back on for the changes to apply. Might have to restart computer, not sure.

Comment: Good idea, did not think about that. Thank you, still new to the site.